# Exchanging limits

Tags: real-analysis

Are there general conditions for the exchange of limits in the following equation?

$$
\lim_{h → 0} \lim_{n → ∞} \sum_{m=0}^n f_m(x + h) = \lim_{n → ∞} \lim_{h → 0}\sum_{m=0}^n f_m(x + h)
$$

The functions $f_m$ are smooth and the limit $\sum_{m=0}^∞f_m(x)$ exists for all $x$ in the domain, which is a compact set.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a power series? Because, as it currently stands, we can simply factorise out the constant $x + h$, and it becomes the product of two independent limits.

Comment: @user837206 I'll clarify the question.

Comment: The finite sum over $m$ is a red herring; just define $f=\sum_m f_m$. The question is really about exchanging the $h$ and $n$ limits.

Comment: @GregMartin It is about the exchange of limits, but one of the limits is over a continuous variable and the other is a discrete one.

Comment: The uniform convergence of the series $\sum f_m$ let you exchange the limits : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence